# White space between snapped shapes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, shapes

I am working on a pattern of a bunch of tiled square shapes. I matched all of the shapes right next to each other until I get that little green "Align" line and let go. When I zoom out I see a little space between most of the shapes. I'm assuming that is so I can see what shapes I'm working with better because when I zoom in the lines go away.

However when I export as a jpeg or png the lines are actually there. I tried it twice to make sure I had all the squares lined up and I'm still getting white space between them. Any idea whats going on?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have 'Align to Pixel Grid' deselected in the Transform panel.

[image]

- Select all of the squares
- Open the **Transform** panel
- Make sure that the checkbox next to '**Align to Pixel Grid**' is not ticked

If you can't see this option in the Transform panel, click 'Show Options' on the drop-down in the top-right of the panel.

Comment: I checked and 'Align to Pixel Grid' is not ticked. I even tried selecting it all, ticking it and unticking and I still get the same results

Answer (score 1):

I would actually set the "Align to Pixels" **ON**, since this will guarantee your shapes are actually aligned to the pixel grid.

From what I see in your screenshot, your anchor points are on fractional pixel coordinates, which will cause these spaces. To confirm, use Pixel Preview (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> on Windows). If you see the gaps there, you need to realign your shapes.